# Interpolating functions returned by NDSolve do not plot

Tags: differential-equations

```
E1 = Sqrt[1 + (del0)^2];
del0 = 1.5;
del1 = 1.5;
a = 1.5
a1 = 1.5
sol = NDSolve[{D[A[x, y, t], t] == 
    E1 - (1 + I*del0)*A[x, y, t] - (Abs[B[x, y, t]])^2 + 
     I*a*Laplacian[A[x, y, t], {x, y}], 
   D[B[x, y, t], t] == 
    A[x, y, t]*Conjugate[B[x, y, t]] - (1 + I*del1)*B[x, y, t] + 
     I*a1*Laplacian[B[x, y, t], {x, y}], A[x, y, 0] == 1.5, 
   B[x, y, 0] == 0.25, A[5, y, t] == A[-5, y, t], 
   A[x, 5, t] == A[x, -5, t], B[5, y, t] == B[-5, y, t], 
   B[x, 5, t] == B[x, -5, t]}, {A, B}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {t, 0, 
   10000}, Rule[MaxSteps, 1000]]
```

I am trying to plot this coupled nonlinear diffrential equation. This is giving a output as a interploting function, but when I try to plot it nothing I see nothing.

Comment: this plots something.  `Plot3D[Re[A[x, y, 4*^-7]] /. First@sol, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`   Note the solver stopped at t~4.3 10^-7,and the results are complex.

Comment: Thank You @george2079. I am struggling in this program to get some solution.

Answer (score 4):

To examine the solutions, we will first extract it from `NDSolve` (we can do it directly but i prefer this way),

```
{Asol, Bsol} = sol[[1, All, 2]];
```

Now, we will assign some random values to the independent variables,

```
Asol /. t -> 0 /. x -> 1 /. y -> 2
```

> `1.5 + 0. I`

```
Bsol /. t -> 0 /. x -> 1 /. y -> 2
```

> `0.25 + 0. I`

which clearly shows that the solutions are complex as suggested by @george2079. The routine way of plotting will not work here, i.e.,

```
Plot3D[{Asol /. t -> 1, Bsol /. t -> 1}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

It will generate empty plot unless, we guide `Plot3D` to understand the nature of the solution.

To do this, we need to specify real and imaginary, using `Re` and `Im`, respectively.

**Plot3D**

```
Plot3D[{Re[Asol /. t -> 1], Re[Bsol /. t -> 1]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[{Im[Asol /. t -> 0], Re[Bsol /. t -> 0]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

**Plot**

You can also plot 2D,

```
Plot[{Re[Asol /. t -> 100 /. x -> 5], Re[Bsol /. t -> 100 /. x -> 5]}, {y, -5, 5},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Edit**

The `Abs[A]` can be plotted like this,

```
Plot3D[Abs[Asol /. t -> 1], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

You can animate the solution with time like this,

```
Ain = Table[Plot3D[Abs[Asol], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 40, 
    ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> Style["t = " <> ToString[t], Bold, 18], 
    ImagePadding -> 30], {t, 0, 4, 0.1}];
Export["C:/tcdata/test.gif", Ain, "DisplayDurations" -> 1, 
         AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would like to discuss something extra on this, if it is comfortable can you give me your email ID.

Comment: This one is giving an empty plot.. Also If i want to integrate over some time period then should i increase the range of t

Comment: @Varunsharma Which one is giving you empty plot?

Comment: If I am trying to plot3d

Comment: http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.65.036610 can you please check this link.

Comment: @Varunsharma I will asap

Comment: @Varunsharma Your PDE's  are not consistent with the research paper. You should include the missing terms.

Comment: Can you help me in this regard to reproduce same results initially

Comment: @Varunsharma I don't understand this model at all.

Comment: I think they have computed this one in fortran by using crank nicolson method. I tried in  mathematica, but i am new to programming so i started facing problem.

Comment: So if you can help me to solve these equation numerically.

Comment: @Varunsharma The problem is not with the software, the problem is with your equations. You should input the correct equations.

Comment: yes, still some problems are there.

Comment: @Varunsharma But not with this particular question. In your new one you have changed the initial conditions.

Comment: @ Maple SE yes in the new question I have changed the initial condition.

Comment: @Varunsharma http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work