# Using AbsArgPlot on parametricNDSolve output

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, complex

I have solved following equation using [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)
$$
\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2} + \left(a + \frac{2}{\pi} b\ \arctan x\right)y = 0
$$

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] + (a + b*((2/Pi)*ArcTan[x]))*
  y[x] == 0, y[-10] == Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a + b]], y'[-10] == (-I)*Sqrt[a + b]*Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a + b]]}, y, {x, -10, 10}, {a, b}]
```

Now I want to plot $ y(x) $ for $ a = 3, b = 1 $ so I have to add following lines to above code

```
y1 = y[3, 1] /. s
AbsArgPlot[y1[x] /. s, {x, -5, 5}]
```

Instead of working it is giving me the following result[image]

A similar question is already posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139053/interpolating-functions-returned-by-ndsolve-do-not-plot) but the answer to that question is that since the output generated is complex so we have to plot real and imaginary parts separately but here I am already aware of that point. Is it not working because of some output type mismatch in the [`AbsArgPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsArgPlot.html) function?

EDIT: **I found out my mistake I am using Kernel 11.0 while AbsArgPlot works for Kernel 12.0**

Comment: The code you've pasted just spews errors for me when I run it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
y1 = s[3, 1]
AbsArgPlot[y1[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: It is still not working. I am getting the same result